# powershell, xml and namespaces

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have some XML:

```xml
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body>
    <P2MessageServiceStatus>
      <CONNECTION>CONNECTION_CONNECTED</CONNECTION>
      <ROUTER>ROUTER_CONNECTED</ROUTER>
    </P2MessageServiceStatus>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

Can't deal with it because of namespaces. Trying a lot, but not working.

```bsh
[string]$xpath = '/SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/P2MessageServiceStatus/@CONNECTION'

$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
[xml]$stuff = $wc.DownloadString($url)

$ns = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $stuff.NameTable
$ns.AddNamespace("SOAP", $xmlns)

$xmlvalue = $stuff.SelectSingleNode($xpath, $ns)
```

> Error - need Namespace manager or XsltContext

If

```bsh
$xmlvalue = $stuff.SelectSingleNode($xpath,'SOAP')
```

> Error - Unable to find overload for "SelectSingleNode"

How to make that xpath query work with namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your `$xmlns` defined. This works:

```
[string]$xpath='/SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/P2MessageServiceStatus/CONNECTION'

$namespaceMgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $stuff.NameTable
$namespace = $stuff.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
$namespaceMgr.AddNamespace("SOAP", $namespace)


$stuff.SelectSingleNode($xpath,$ns)
```

**Note**: You can also *access the nodes like properties* with `PowerShell`:

```
$stuff.DocumentElement.Body.P2MessageServiceStatus.CONNECTION
```

Comment: if i use $stuff.SelectSingleNode($xpath,$namespace) its not work at all.  If $stuff.SelectSingleNode($xpath,$namespaceMgr) it returns value but also i got exception 'cant find reload for SelectSingleNode and 2 methods...' ... is it normal ?

Comment: omg i got that exception on work pc but not on my server... it works..thank you a lot

Comment: if i see variable $namespaceMgr i will see 3 of them - xmlns,xml, SOAP. could it be an errors reason?

Comment: My xml to parse starts with `<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<u:GetInfoResponse xmlns:u="urn:dslforum-org:service:WLANConfiguration:1">...`. How can I parse it? This works: `$xml=[xml]$xml.Content;Write-Host $xml.xml` which gives `version="1.0"` but `$xml.DocumentElement` prints nothing. Do I need a `namespacemanager` and `$xpath`?

Comment: Instead of `$stuff.SelectSingleNode($xpath,$ns)` you mean `$stuff.SelectSingleNode($xpath,$namespace)`?